# mac php shell execute svnversion

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9 and MAMP with PHP 5.5.10.

When I try to execute:

```
echo shell_exec('svnversion');
```

or

```
exec("svn diff -r " . $this->from_revision . ":HEAD ", $diff);
```

It simply doesn't show anything.
The same code works perfectly with Ubuntu.

How can I make this work with MAMP?

Comment: how should we know? do you have svn installed on the mac? is `svnversion` in the path of whatever shell php's using for this?

Comment: Try executing `which svn` on a terminal and check if subversion is installed, and in which path.

Comment: svn is installed in /usr/bin/svn, and svn works perfectly on terminal

Comment: Have you got display_errors turned on? Are any errors reported?

Comment: yes errors on, no errors about this